# Magento 2 - media URL

Tags: magento2, url, media

I have recently migrated a Magento 1.9.x site to Magento 2.2.2.  On my product pages, I have noticed that one attribute (which is Text Area), whenever I used Magento directives such as `{{media url=...}}` the media url path is not resolved.  However, I have other Text Area attributes and the media url paths work as expected.  Not sure where to look to figuring out what is causing this.

Any advice would be appreciated.